# flutter_webview_plugin: Choose File not working in Flutter WebView (working in Google Chrome)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-file

I am working with [flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.4.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) and its working successfully but there is one issue that File Chooser is not opening.

I have to choose one file from WebView but its showing "No apps can perform this action."

I am using following code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: _connectionStatus == ConnectivityResult.none
          ? Scaffold(body: NoInternetWidget())
          : WebviewScaffold(
              url: "https://app.capsavvycrm.com/admin",
              withZoom: true,
              primary: true,
              enableAppScheme: true,
              withLocalStorage: true,
              withLocalUrl: true,
              resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
              withOverviewMode: true,
             
              initialChild: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
              javascriptChannels: jsChannels,
              withJavascript: true,
              allowFileURLs: true,
            ),
    );
  }
```

**Tested on:**

Samsung **Galaxy J8 9.0:**

- Google Chrome : Working (Camera, Files),
- WebView : Working (Camera, Files)

Samsung **C9 Pro 8.0.0:**

- Google Chrome : Working,

[image]

- WebView : ***Not Working***

[image]

**Screenshots :**

I don't know why its happening. Anyone can help please?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?